# how to get pi_image from array in table view

Tags: objective-c

```
(
        {
        property =         {
            "p_address" = sdfsdf;
            "p_asking_price" = "50000.00";
            "p_category_type" = 1;
            "p_created" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
            "p_description" = sdfsdf;
            "p_id" = 2;
            "p_is_new_property" = 1;
            "p_modified" = "2013-04-08 15:40:25";
            "p_no_of_bedroom" = 1;
            "p_no_of_otherroom" = 1;
            "p_no_of_wc" = 2;
            "p_title" = sadf;
            "p_type" = demo;
        };
        "property_images" =         (
        );
        "property_local_information" =         (
                        {
                "li_label" = "Nearby Transport";
                "li_order" = 1;
                "pli_distance" = "";
                "pli_logo" = "";
                "pli_title" = "";
            }
        );
        "property_sale_history" =         (
                        {
                "psh_history" = sdsdfsd;
            },
                        {
                "psh_history" = sdfdfds;
            }
        );
        "property_videos" =         (
        );
    },
        {
        property =         {
            "p_address" = dfgsdfg;
            "p_asking_price" = "44222.00";
            "p_category_type" = "";
            "p_created" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
            "p_description" = "Updated by a staff meber (demo2@gmail.com)";
            "p_id" = 3;
            "p_is_new_property" = 1;
            "p_modified" = "2013-04-09 03:05:09";
            "p_no_of_bedroom" = 0;
            "p_no_of_otherroom" = 0;
            "p_no_of_wc" = 0;
            "p_title" = "Test Update";
            "p_type" = sdfgsdfgsdg;
        };
        "property_images" =         (
                        {
                "pi_image" = "prop_img_1594785781_3.png";
            }
        );
        "property_local_information" =         (
                        {
                "li_label" = "Nearby College";
                "li_order" = 4;
                "pli_distance" = utyutyu;
                "pli_logo" = "";
                "pli_title" = tyutyu;
            }
        );
        "property_sale_history" =         (
                        {
                "psh_history" = testing;
            },
                        {
                "psh_history" = tyutyutut;
            }
        );
        "property_videos" =         (
                        {
                "pv_video" = "prop_vid_730342365_3.flv";
            }
        );
    },
```

Comment: are you using json concept?

Comment: value=[theArray valueForKeyPath:@"property_images. pi_image"];

Answer (score 2):

Try this if your using json concept

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:"your url link"];     
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *json = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableArray *piimage=[json valueForKey:@"pi_image"];
NSLog(@"%@",piimage);
```